# Matching Paypal's IPN Variable with Backend Variable

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am implementing a PayPal integration system, I have successfully integrated with PayPal and create a database to store the information.

I am wishing to print a receipt after returning to my successful payment landing page.

But I came to a problem - before submitting to Paypal, I do not store anything (not user, nor anything). What can I do to match with Paypal's return IPN variable?

I do not wish the user to enter username nor email beforehand, I wish to have something that is done backend and is done by the system and not by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All PayPal APIs and transaction creation mechanisms support an order/invoice number (INVNUM) and a 'CUSTOM' variable, both of which can store a unique value at transaction creation time.

The value of both of these variables will then be returned to you in the IPN for reconciliation purposes.

Comment: What should be the custom variable be? 
I mean what should I send over there that won't change as after reload in short period

Comment: And for anyone wondering
[this link](https://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php) has a very good explanation

Comment: Well if you are using those old web 1.0 buttons, the variable names are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/ .   There are much newer and nicer integrations available, however, like this one: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client